# JPA Select and Count over Map

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, eclipselink

I have a simple Quiz Game with a Player class that has a List of Game objects. 
In the Game class I store the answered questions with a Boolean, if the question was answered correctly, in a Map:

```java
private Map<Question, Boolean> questions;
```

Now I want to create a Query which will return the amount of the right answered questions of a Game:

```sql
SELECT g.id, (SELECT COUNT(gq) FROM g.questions gq WHERE VALUE(gq) = TRUE)
FROM Player p 
JOIN p.games g 
WHERE p.name = :name
```

This does not work.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Is there an error? What output are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: Yes there is an error: java.lang.NullPointerException. I expect to get the number of how many questions are true, so how many value fields in the map equal true.

Comment: Try changing (SELECT COUNT(gq) FROM g.questions gq WHERE VALUE(gq) = TRUE) to COUNT(SELECT gq FROM g.questions gq WHERE VALUE(gq) = TRUE)

Comment: Showing the NPE error and where it comes from generally helps others help you as well. Could you not also just use 'SELECT g.id, count(gq) FROM Game g join g.questions gq WHERE value(gq) = TRUE GROUP BY g.id' ?